# Generating privacy policy and terms of use for Notion-integrated Telegram bot

Tags: privacy-policy

I'm writing a Telegram bot that in part is a public Notion integration (it requests authorization and stores users' access tokens internally). Notion requires all public integrations to have links to their privacy policy and terms of use documents.
Now there is a bunch of online generators for these documents, but they all seem to be aimed at either websites or mobile apps. My integration is neither. Technically it does have a website part, but only as part of the implementation of Notion's OAuth - all it does is accept requests from Notion, saves tokens to the database and redirects the user back to the bot. And, maybe, a static home page with a link to the bot.

I am not a company with a thousand employees. I'm just one person, not a law expert, who just wants to launch a Telegram bot. How should I go about doing this? I am leaning towards using one of these generators in their website mode. I realize that I will have to say that I in fact do collect personal data (Notion access tokens).

Most likely, the only ones using the bot will be me and my friends and family. But then again, who knows - maybe it'll catch on...

Any advice is very welcome.